# Need to edit themes HTML code

Tags: themes, css, html

I am working on a small online shop and I am using Averta Phlox theme. As I encounter they have bug in a shopping cart. The cart do not work on mobile phones, as I can work a little fix for it using simple css and html, I am able to fix this bug. But I can't find the place for HTML part in this because it use aux design and elementor plugin.

Maybe someone can suggest the place how to find the necessary part of the code. It is a Phlox cart widget what creates cart function in header file.

My test site is here - [SHOP](https://eogame.eu/rietumi2/?post_type=product)

I would love to get some suggestion in this situation, because averta support are ignoring this issue for a 3 years. 
Thanks and sorry for bad English, it's  not my native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you search the theme source code for the CSS class that is used for the cart icon ("aux-shopping-basket" or "aux-phone-off" or "aux-action-on-click")?

Then you could create a child theme and copy the original file and then edit the copied file to fix the error.

What is the fix?

Comment: My fix is to delete aux-phone-off and edit css to make cart popup work on mobile. Not the best fix but thats the first thing what I tried with inspect element. 

I tried to search for CSS class name but without success.  They I added lot of extra folders with extra templates, hooks etc...

Comment: If there is a bug I think that you should report it to the theme developers. Include your suggested fixed too. This would get the bug fixed for everyone.

Comment: I downloaded a free version of the theme (version 2.3.5) and found '`aux-phone-off`' in `phlox/auxin/auxin-include/include/templates/templates-post.php` in the `auxin_wc_add_to_cart()` function.
I doubt that this will work if copied into a child theme but the function has a filter at the bottom: '`auxin_shopping_basket`'
You could use that filter to call str_replace() to remove 'aux-phone-off'

Comment: Big thanks @Damien Carbery .  I was able to finaly find that little sh*t. Also I am not very goot at filters maybe you should help me how to make correct filter to delete aux-phone-off tag correctly without harming actual file.

Comment: Here's a gist with a plugin that will remove the "aux-phone-off" class name. You can save the file, upload it to wp-content/plugins and activate it. If there are any problems you can easily deactivate it. It may need some adjustments in case it removes more instances of the class name than you need. Please activate it, add your CSS changes somewhere and test it thoroughly. https://gist.github.com/damiencarbery/20894fdf07a8d7191191717f7722ca5a

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) would be a great option to edit CSS and HTML. If you can get by without editing HTML, you should be able to add CSS using Elementor or another plugin such as [wp add custom css](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/)

If you're having trouble finding the class name try searching [their docs](https://docs.phlox.pro/) or doing a directory wide search - here's how you do that in VS Code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572974/vs-code-search-for-text-in-all-files-in-a-directory